# Using Google.OrTools with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, or-tools

I want to write a Shift Scheduling Programm using C# and the Google.OrTools.
As a starting point i am using the example provided by the Or Team.
Compiling and running their test programm in the shell works like a charm, however trying the same in Visual Studio is not working out for me.

I have installed the package Google.OrTools via NuGet but running the test program Visual Studio says it is unable to find Google.OrTools.

The exact error is:

> Die Datei oder Assembly "Google.OrTools, Version=7.0.6546.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=53dbb1ea090cbef7" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden.

Isn't it enough to add the reference via NuGet?

Comment: Have you tried to restore nuget packages? Are there any yellow exclamation marks below dependencies in your project? Are there any messages in the ouput or error view?

Comment: Restoring the project had no effect at all. Also, there are no exclamation marks or anything else suspicious. The only error i am getting is the System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone encountering the same issue:

It seems like the Google.OrTools.dll was not correctly copied to the program path, so i did this myself.
Afterwards i got a different exception, reading System.BadImageFormatException.
To solve this, you have to specify the build platform form "Any CPU" to "x64".

Afterwards it worked like a charm, as well.